# Grep - regular expression to match multiple key-value pairs and return single line

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

I have following input:

```
TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG4 VALUE4;TAG5 VALUE5;sometext
TAG1 VALUE1;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG4 VALUE4;TAG5 VALUE5;sometext
TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG4 VALUE4;TAG5 VALUE5
TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG5 VALUE5;sometext
TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;
```

I need following output:

```
TAG2 VALUE2;TAG3 VALUE3;TAG5 VALUE5;
TAG3 VALUE3;TAG5 VALUE5;
TAG2 VALUE2;TAG3 VALUE3;TAG5 VALUE5;
TAG2 VALUE2;TAG3 VALUE3;TAG5 VALUE5;
TAG2 VALUE2;
```

or, alternatively same as above, but only values

I've tried following:

```
grep -oP '(?<=TAG2 ).*?(?=;)|(?<=TAG3 ).*?(?=;)|(?<=TAG5 ).*?(?=;)'
```

it works, but every value is in separate line:

```
VALUE2
VALUE3
VALUE5
```

I cannot assume that all lines will have all tags, so I really need one line of output per one line of input. Native Linux tools preferred - sed, awk, grep etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a perl way:

```
$ perl -ne 'print $1," " while(/(?<=TAG[235] )(.*?)(?=;)/g); print "\n";'  in.txt
```

Edit according to comment:

```
$ perl -ne 'print $1," " while(/(?<=(?:DEV|SRC|DST|ACT) )(.*?)(?=;)/g); print "\n";'  in.txt
```

**In action:**

```
$ cat in.txt
TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG4 VALUE4;TAG5 VALUE5;sometext
TAG1 VALUE1;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG4 VALUE4;TAG5 VALUE5;sometext
TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG4 VALUE4;TAG5 VALUE5
TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG5 VALUE5;sometext
TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;

$ perl -ne 'print $1," " while(/(?<=TAG[235] )(.*?)(?=;)/g); print "\n";'  in.txt
VALUE2 VALUE3 VALUE5 
VALUE3 VALUE5 
VALUE2 VALUE3 
VALUE2 VALUE3 VALUE5 
VALUE2
```

Comment: that is nice one, but in real world tags are not that similar (for instance DEV, SRC, DST, ACT) - can your pattern be updated to work in this scenario?

Comment: @M42 - works fairly well. Tried to convert it into grep/PCRE but I can't make it. Also TAG1 will match TAG11 (for ma data it is SRC and SRCP overlapping). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @lubas: `TAG1` will not match `TAG11` because of the space after `TAGn`.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{print $2, $4, $7}' file
TAG2 VALUE2;TAG3 VALUE3;TAG5 VALUE5
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}` sets input and output field separator as `;`.
- `{print $2, $4, $7}` prints the 2nd, 4th and 7th fields based on that separator.

---

> The reason I am looking to parse key/value pairs is that not
>   necessarily all keys are present, and not necessarily in the same
>   column (but at least they are in specific order if present, TAG1 is
>   first, TAG2 next etc...)

Then something like this should make it:

```
awk -v values="TAG1 TAG5"
       'BEGIN{split(values, vals, " ")}
        {a[$1]=$2}
        END{for (i in vals) print vals[i], a[vals[i]]}'
     RS=";" file
```

- `-v values="TAG1 TAG5"` passwes to awk the values to analyze.
- `'BEGIN{split(values, vals, " ")}` stores them into the `vals[]` array.
- `{a[$1]=$2}` saves the `a["TAG1"] = "VAL1"` matching.
- `END{for (i in vals) print vals[i], a[vals[i]]}'` prints the matches.
- `RS=";"` sets the record separator as `;`, so that we can work with couple of values from the files.

Examples:

```
$ awk -v values="TAG1 TAG3" 'BEGIN{split(values, vals, " ")} {a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in vals) print vals[i], a[vals[i]]}' RS=";" file
TAG1 VALUE1
TAG3 VALUE3
$ awk -v values="TAG1 TAG6" 'BEGIN{split(values, vals, " ")} {a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in vals) print vals[i], a[vals[i]]}' RS=";" file
TAG1 VALUE1
TAG6
```

Comment: The reason I am looking to parse key/value pairs is that not necessarily all keys are present, and not necessarily in the same column (but at least they are in specific order if present, TAG1 is first, TAG2 next etc...)

Comment: @lubas see my updated answer with a more broad approach.

Comment: on 27k lines long input it responds with only 2 lines (TAG1 VALUE1 in 1st line  and TAG2 VALUE2 in 2nd line).

Answer (score 0):

Using pure BASH:

```
l='TAG1 VALUE1;TAG2 VALUE2;sometext;TAG3 VALUE3;sometext;TAG4 VALUE4;TAG5 VALUE5;sometext'
( IFS=';' && read -a arr <<< "$l"; echo "${arr[1]}; ${arr[3]}; ${arr[6]};" )
TAG2 VALUE2; TAG3 VALUE3; TAG5 VALUE5;
```

- `IFS=';'` makes delimiter as `;` while reading the line into array.

Comment: Same as with awk - cannot guarantee presence and specific position of all tags

Comment: In that case I need some clarification and few more examples of input/output.